# promise $http returns undefined data

Tags: angularjs, web-services, api

Sentry reports me a bug when i try to process the callback function from an API request, the success function returns me undefined in data.

Here is my code

--- Controller ---

```
angular.module('candidateLanguagesController', [])

.controller('candidateLanguagesController',[ '$scope', '$http', 'CandidateLanguages', 'Helper',function($scope, $http, CandidateLanguages, Helper) {


    $scope.init = function(uuid)
    {
        $scope.uuid = uuid;

        $scope.candidateLanguages = {};

        CandidateLanguages.show($scope.uuid)
            .success(function(data) {

                $scope.candidateLanguages = data.data;          

                if( Helper.isEmpty($scope.candidateLanguages) ){
                    $scope.candidateLanguages.push({id:'newLanguage', language_id:'', languagelevel_id:''});
                }

            }).error(function(data) {
                    console.log(data);
            });

    };  }]);
```

--- Service ---

```
angular.module('candidateLanguagesService', [])

.factory('CandidateLanguages', ['$http','$location',function($http,$location) {

    var host = $location.protocol();
    var domain = $location.host();
    var url = host+'://'+domain;

    return {

        show : function(uuid) {
            return $http.get(url+'/api/v1/candidates/'+uuid+'/languages');
        }
    }

}]);
```

--- App ---

```
var SignupSPA = angular.module('SignupSPA', ['candidateLanguagesController', 'candidateLanguagesService','helperService']);
```

--JSON response--

```
{"data":[{"id":51571,"language_id":6,"languagelevel_id":4,"name":"English","percent":"75%","level_description":"Puedo conversar de manera fluida y sin errores. (TOEFL CBT > 240 o PBT > 580)"}]}
```

Comment: what do you see in the network tab for the request?

Comment: @PankajParkar you are right, i had a mistake when i posted the issue, i modified the code to the correct one

Comment: @IsaiahLee returns me this: 

{"data":[{"id":51571,"language_id":6,"languagelevel_id":4,"name":"English","percent":"75%","level_description":"Puedo conversar de manera fluida y sin errores. (TOEFL CBT > 240 o PBT > 580)"}]}